# Using form, save :member_id, :group_id and :content to GroupMessage model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**(What I would like to do)**
Using form, I would like to save some data into GroupMessage model and at the same time,
to show the group message on the page where I filled in the form(groups/show?id=).

**(What I did)**
    I wrote the code as below.
    After pushing Create Group Message button, 
    I went to the page,
        http:// localhost:3000/ groups/:id/group_messages

```
and got an error 
"We're sorry, but something went wrong".
```

Help!!

**(group/show?id=)**

```
<%= form_for([@group, @group_message]) do |f| %>
  <% if @group_message.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@group_message.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this group_message from being saved:</h2>

<ul>
 <% @group_message.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
 <% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :member_id %><br />
 <%= f.number_field :member_id %>
</div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :group_id %><br/>
  <%= f.number_field :group_id %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :content %><br/>
<%= f.text_area :content %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**(groups_controller)**

```
def show
 @group = Group.find(params[:id])
 @group_message = Group.find(params[:id]).group_messages.build
 if !checklogin? then return end
 groupfriends = GroupInMember.where(:member_id => session[:login].id)
 gflist = '('
 groupfriends.each do |gf|
 gflist += gf.member_id.to_s + ","
 end
 gflist += session[:login].id.to_s + ')'
 @query = "select * from group_messages where member_id in " +  gflist 
 @group_messages = GroupMessage.find_by_sql(@query)
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @group_messages }
 end
end
```

(GroupMessage table)
    create_table "group_messages", :force => true do |t|
     t.integer  "member_id"
     t.text     "content"
     t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
     t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
     t.integer  "group_id"
    end

Comment: What exactly was the error? 'We are sorry...' is perhaps what is shown on the page. What was the error in the log file?

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the error I got. ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: group_id):

Comment: So, you just need to add 'attr_accessible :group_id` in your `GroupMessage` model